# Save/Retrieve the "Rich Formatted Text" in the database without losing its Format

Tags: android, commonsware-cwac

I am using [commonsguy / cwac-richedit Library](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-richedit) for Rich Text Editing. After doing so i am saving the formatted text in the database. But when i retrieve the saved formatted string its formatting is removed.

I want to know that how to save/retrieve the text from the database without losing format.

Comment: Please post your code - what have you tried, and what exactly does not work?

Comment: Looks like your are just retrieving just the text from your application, and not in rich format.

Comment: @NaveenBabu is there any way to do so?

Comment: @ShajeelAfzal i am not sure of the library you use. But a rich text should look like this `"<p>I am using <a href="https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-richedit" rel="nofollow">commonsguy / cwac-richedit Library</a> for Rich Text Editing."` . If you can retrieve this kind of code, you can save it as such (or use StringUtils.escapeHTML() from apache commonUtil lib)  and save it directly to DB.

Comment: Yes you are right. :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`EditText` uses HTML markup (limited set). Key Interfaces for this type of markup text  being `Spanned` and `Spannable`.

`EditText` uses `Editable` to represent text, which implements `Spannable`.

`Html` class is provided for conversions between markup and Spanned text, you can use it as well:

```
    //--suppose this is typed to an EditText called et --
    Spanned s = Html.fromHtml("<i>Hi</i> There ! <b>how're you ?</b>");
    et.setText(s);

    //--save to string--
    Editable e = et.getText();
    String s2 = Html.toHtml(e);

    //--restore from string--
    Spanned s3 = Html.fromHtml(s2);
    et.setText(s3);
```

Comment: +1, for being the best we have. Note that while `fromHtml()` and `toHtml()` are roughly aligned with what `TextView`/`EditText`/`RichEditText` can support, there are things the widgets and `Spanned` can do that `fromHtml()` does not translate and `toHtml()` does not generate. Somebody needs to create equivalents of `fromHtml()` and `toHtml()` than handle all the `CharacterStyle` variants. I'm kinda hoping that "somebody" isn't me... :-)

Comment: @CommonsWare Ah I see, lots of `Span` classes are there for `CharacterStyle`. I only knew about html tags (you posted a list of those). Thanks.

Comment: @CommonsWare i have applied every style to the text entered (i.e, `BOLD`, `ITALIC`, `UNDERLINE`, etc) all of them work fine except `STRIKETHROUGH`. I mean all of them save and load fine in the database except `STRIKETHROUGH` effect! `STRIKETHROUGH` is applied to the text but not saved in the database.

Comment: @ShajeelAfzal: That would suggest that `toHtml()` does not support the `strike` tag.

Comment: @CommonsWare any solution for that sir?

Answer (score 0):

Just Use: **JSONField** in PostgresSQL. That Miraculosly solved the issue.
Yesterday, I was facing the same. Solved it via

> JSONField in PostgreSQL