# How can I capture the formatting of my EditText text, so that bold words show as bold next time I display them in a TextView

Tags: android, android-edittext

Edit:

my app allows users to post comments for all other users to see. I want to allow users to make certain words in their comment bold or italic etc, so that when they post a comment other people will also be able to see the bold words etc.

At the moment i am able to make the words bold but when the text is saved to my remote database server it is saved as normal text and i am unable to find out which words were bold and which arn't.

How can I preserve the bold/italic/underlined... formatting when saving the text from an EditText?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is one way to achieve this.

You can store HTML content and display HTML content in TextView.

Just look at this [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17141633/624069).

Here is [Sample link](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-richedit).

Answer (score 1):

Quite easily.
Use [EditText.getText](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/EditText.html#getText%28%29) to get the text, which implements [Spanned](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Spanned.html) interface.

Then you need to somehow mark bold parts within text, for this you may use good old HTML format, which means that you'll end up with text (storable in database) with some formatting.
Use [Html.toHtml](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Html.html#toHtml%28android.text.Spanned%29) to turn Spanned to (HTML) String. Save result to DB or where you need.

Reverse process is to get your HTML String and convert it to Spanned, then set it bact to EditText. Use [Html.fromHtml](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Html.html#toHtml%28android.text.Spanned%29) to accomplish this.

Answer (score 0):

```
final SpannableStringBuilder sb = new SpannableStringBuilder("Text from the edit Text");

    final StyleSpan bss = new StyleSpan(android.graphics.Typeface.BOLD); // Span to make text bold
    final StyleSpan iss = new StyleSpan(android.graphics.Typeface.ITALIC);//Span to make text italic
    sb.setSpan(bss, 0, 10, Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE); // make first 10 characters Bold 
    sb.setSpan(iss, 10, 20, Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE); // make last 10 characters Italic
    //Set text or save it in db
    etx.setText(sb);
```

Comment: I have added to my question